# limsup definition in Alexandroff compactification of C

Tags: complex-analysis, compactness, limsup-and-liminf

In the Alexandroff, or one-point compactification of $\mathbb{C}$ (by adding a point $\infty$), consider a function $f:\Omega (\subset \mathbb{C}) \to \mathbb{R}$. I was asked to justify the following definition of $\limsup$ by somebody:

> $\displaystyle\limsup_{z \to p} f(z) = \displaystyle\lim_{r \to 0^+} (\sup\{ f(z) : z \in \Omega\ \cap\ U(p;r)\})$

Where $U(p;r)$ is defined as $D(p;r)^*$ (punctured disc around $p$ of radius $r$) if $p \in \mathbb{C}$,and as the annulus centered at $0$ and going from radius $\dfrac{1}{r}$ to $\infty$ if $p \notin \mathbb{C}$. The set of annuli, with $\infty$ added, form basic open sets in the one-point compactification.

I have to justify the following definition by showing that the limit on the right side exists. However, I need a clue on how to start, because in  many limit existence problems we have shown the underlying subsequence as Cauchy and used completeness to establish a limit, or figured out a candidate limit by hook or crook. I am not able to do either here.

Thanking all in advance.

Comment: HINT: Call $s(r)= \sup \mbox{etc...}$. Then $s(r)$ is a monotone function, hence limits always exist. More geerally, if $f: X \to \Bbb{R}$ is any real function defined on any topological space $(X, \tau)$, and $p \in X$, then it is defined $$\limsup_{x \to p} f(x) = \inf_{p \in U \in \tau} \{ \sup_{x \in U} f(x) \}$$

Comment: @Crostul I have the answer to this question already. Thank you anyway.